# VTK cannot construct a proper closed surface with vtkClipClosedSurface

Tags: python, python-3.x, vtk, triangulation, mayavi

Here's a rough explanation of what I do in `vtk`:

1. Create a surface (a minimal surface, not too relevant what it is, the geometry is important though: the gyroid has two labyrinths that are completely shut off from each other).
2. use `vtkClipClosedSurface` to shut off one of the labyrinths so that I get an object that has no open surfaces anymore. A [regular surface looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmR9N.jpg), with a closed surface it looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Yi5J.jpg).

Here's my problem: For more complicated versions of my structure, I get this: [image: broken surfaces in the lower right]
Can you see how on the top left it works fine and near the bottom right it stops creating surfaces? Sometimes I also get really weird triangles in that last part.

To my understanding `vtkClipClosedSurface` knows from the surface normals where to close a surface and where not. The thing is: The normals of my structure are fine and they all point in the right direction. If you take a closer look on the structure you will notice that the lower part is basically an inversion of the top part that changes gradually, all in one surface.

I tried to modify my structure before cutting with many things like `vtkSmoothPolyDataFilter`, `vtkCleanPolyData` or `vtkPolyDataNormals`. I even tried extracting the boundary surfaces with `vtkFeatureEdges`, which led to an even worse result. Even `vtkFillHolesFilter` didn't yield any acceptable results. My surface seems flawless and easy enough to create a boundary.

I have no idea what else to try. This happens for other structures, too. Fixing it with a CAD tool is out of question, because it is supposed to work out of box. Please help me!

Here's another example of a geometry that doesn't close the surface properly. This time I used `vtkFillHolesFilter` which results in surfaces on the inside of the structure, while they should only occupy the boundary of te object.
[image: Another geometry with the error]

In case you need a more detailed rundown of my pipeline, here goes:

1. create surface using `mayavi.mlab.contour3d`
2. get the `PolyData` by extracting the `actor.mapper.input`
3. convert format from `tvtk` to regular `vtk`
4. `vtkClipClosedSurface` with a plane collection that cuts away part of the structure (errors occur when the plane collection is the same as the structure boundary)
5. visualize it

Edit: Okay, this did not receive enough attention, so I constructed a [minimal, complete and verifiable working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the behaviour:

```
import numpy as np
import vtk  # VTK version 7.0
from mayavi import mlab  # mayavi version 4.4.4
from mayavi.api import Engine, OffScreenEngine
from tvtk.api import tvtk


def schwarz_D(x, y, z, linear_term=0):
        """This is the function for the Schwarz Diamond level surface."""
        return (np.sin(x) * np.sin(y) * np.sin(z) + np.sin(x) * np.cos(y) * np.cos(z) +
                np.cos(x) * np.sin(y) * np.cos(z) + np.cos(x) * np.cos(y) * np.sin(z)) - linear_term * z


def plane_collection(xn, x, yn, y, zn, z):
        """Defines the 6 planes for cutting rectangular objects to the right size."""
        plane1 = vtk.vtkPlane()
        plane1.SetOrigin(x, 0, 0)
        plane1.SetNormal(-1, 0, 0)
        plane2 = vtk.vtkPlane()
        plane2.SetOrigin(0, y, 0)
        plane2.SetNormal(0, -1, 0)
        plane3 = vtk.vtkPlane()
        plane3.SetOrigin(0, 0, z)
        plane3.SetNormal(0, 0, -1)
        plane4 = vtk.vtkPlane()
        plane4.SetOrigin(xn, 0, 0)
        plane4.SetNormal(1, 0, 0)
        plane5 = vtk.vtkPlane()
        plane5.SetOrigin(0, yn, 0)
        plane5.SetNormal(0, 1, 0)
        plane6 = vtk.vtkPlane()
        plane6.SetOrigin(0, 0, zn)
        plane6.SetNormal(0, 0, 1)

        plane_list = [plane4, plane1, plane5, plane2, plane6, plane3]
        planes = vtk.vtkPlaneCollection()
        for item in plane_list:
            planes.AddItem(item)
        return planes

[nx, ny, nz] = [2, 2, 8]  # amount of unit cells
cell_size = 1
gradient_value = 0.04  # only values below 0.1 produce the desired geometry; this term is essential
x, y, z = np.mgrid[-cell_size*(nx + 1)/2:cell_size*(nx + 1)/2:100j,
                   -cell_size*(ny + 1)/2:cell_size*(ny + 1)/2:100j,
                   -cell_size*(nz + 1)/2:cell_size*(nz + 1)/2:100*2j] * np.pi / (cell_size/2)

# engine = Engine()
engine = OffScreenEngine()  # do not start mayavi GUI
engine.start()
fig = mlab.figure(figure=None, engine=engine)
contour3d = mlab.contour3d(x, y, z, schwarz_D(x, y, z, gradient_value), figure=fig)

scene = engine.scenes[0]
actor = contour3d.actor.actors[0]
iso_surface = scene.children[0].children[0].children[0]
iso_surface.contour.minimum_contour = 0
iso_surface.contour.number_of_contours = 1
iso_surface.compute_normals = False

iso_surface.contour.auto_update_range = False

mlab.draw(fig)
# mlab.show()  # enable if you want to see the mayavi GUI

polydata = tvtk.to_vtk(actor.mapper.input)  # convert tvtkPolyData to vtkPolyData

# Move object to the coordinate center to make clipping easier later on.
center_coords = np.array(polydata.GetCenter())
center = vtk.vtkTransform()
center.Translate(-center_coords[0], -center_coords[1], -center_coords[2])
centerFilter = vtk.vtkTransformPolyDataFilter()
centerFilter.SetTransform(center)
centerFilter.SetInputData(polydata)
centerFilter.Update()

# Reverse normals in order to receive a closed surface after clipping
reverse = vtk.vtkReverseSense()
reverse.SetInputConnection(centerFilter.GetOutputPort())
reverse.ReverseNormalsOn()
reverse.ReverseCellsOn()
reverse.Update()

bounds = np.asarray(reverse.GetOutput().GetBounds())
clip = vtk.vtkClipClosedSurface()
clip.SetInputConnection(reverse.GetOutputPort())
clip.SetTolerance(10e-3)
# clip.TriangulationErrorDisplayOn()  # enable to see errors for not watertight surfaces
clip.SetClippingPlanes(plane_collection(bounds[0] + cell_size/2, bounds[1] - cell_size/2,
                                        bounds[2] + cell_size/2, bounds[3] - cell_size/2,
                                        bounds[4] + cell_size/2, bounds[5] - cell_size/2))
clip.Update()

# Render the result
mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
mapper.SetInputConnection(clip.GetOutputPort())
actor = vtk.vtkActor()
actor.SetMapper(mapper)
renderer = vtk.vtkRenderer()
renderWindow = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
renderWindow.AddRenderer(renderer)
renderWindowInteractor = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
renderWindowInteractor.SetRenderWindow(renderWindow)
renderer.AddActor(actor)
renderWindow.Render()
renderWindowInteractor.Start()
```

This really is a short as it gets, I stripped as much as I could. The problem still persists and I can't figure out a solution.

Comment: No idea myself, but have you tried the vtk mailing list.  The question seems to be vtk specific - maybe even a vtk bug?

Comment: I posted to the mailing list a few times before and never got an answer (even on simpler matters). So I decided to stick to SO instead. Especially in a case as "large" as this one I doubt someone will provide a solution. In case this fails, I will post there as a last resort.

Comment: I would suggest trying the ML again with a simpler case where the bug can be reproduced, as well as the code and dataset to reproduce the issue.

Comment: You can also open an issue in vtk issue tracker https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/vtk/issues

Answer (score 1):

Great problem and thanks for the example.

I was able to get this to work in `pyvista` with some modifications:

```py
import numpy as np
import pyvista as pv


def schwarz_D(x, y, z, linear_term=0):
        """This is the function for the Schwarz Diamond level surface."""
        return (np.sin(x) * np.sin(y) * np.sin(z) + np.sin(x) * np.cos(y) * np.cos(z) +
                np.cos(x) * np.sin(y) * np.cos(z) + np.cos(x) * np.cos(y) * np.sin(z)) - linear_term * z


# Create the grid
[nx, ny, nz] = [2, 2, 8]  # amount of unit cells
cell_size = 1
gradient_value = 0.04  # only values below 0.1 produce the desired geometry; this term is essential
x, y, z = np.mgrid[-cell_size*(nx + 1)/2:cell_size*(nx + 1)/2:100j,
                   -cell_size*(ny + 1)/2:cell_size*(ny + 1)/2:100j,
                   -cell_size*(nz + 1)/2:cell_size*(nz + 1)/2:100*2j] * np.pi / (cell_size/2)


# make a grid and exclude cells below 0.1
grid = pv.StructuredGrid(x, y, z)
grid['scalars'] = schwarz_D(x, y, z, gradient_value).ravel(order='F')
contour = grid.clip_scalar(value=0.1)


# make a bunch of clips
# bounds = contour.bounds
# contour.clip(origin=(bounds[0] + cell_size/2, 0, 0), normal='-x', inplace=True)
# contour.clip(origin=(0, bounds[1] - cell_size/2, 0), normal='-y', inplace=True)
# contour.clip(origin=(0, 0, bounds[2] + cell_size/2), normal='-z', inplace=True)
# contour.clip(origin=(bounds[3] - cell_size/2, 0, 0), normal='x', inplace=True)
# contour.clip(origin=(0, bounds[4] + cell_size/2, 0), normal='y', inplace=True)
# contour.clip(origin=(0, 0, bounds[5] - cell_size/2), normal='z', inplace=True)

contour.plot(smooth_shading=True, color='w')
```

[image]

I'm not sure why you're using clipping planes, and I think that you would be better off simply limiting your x, y, and z ranges put into creating the grids.  That way, you wouldn't have to clip the final mesh.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [pymeshfix](https://github.com/pyvista/pymeshfix).  I had a very similar problem with some low-res mandelbulbs I was generating.

You may also want ot check out pyvista, it's a nice python wrapper for vtk.